# Why Angular proxy configuration does not work?

Tags: angular, angular8

My proxy configuration `proxy.conf.json` is:

```
{
    "http://localhost:4200": {
        "target": "http://182.168.0.240:80/",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

I have run application using command:

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json
```

I send request from `http://localhost:4200` address to `http://182.168.0.240:80/`.

In Chrome network I see that request came to:

```
http://182.168.0.240:80/accept
```

With CORS problem:

```
has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Request is:

```
   return this.httpClient.post(environment.serverUrl + 'accept', order).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

Where `environment.serverUrl` is:

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    serverUrl: 'http://182.168.0.240:80/',
};
```

I have tried replace configuration path to:

```
{
    "*": {}
}
```

And this:

```
{
    "*/": {}
}
```

No result

Comment: The proxy doesn't do anything if your client isn't making requests to the dev server...

Comment: I just want to send data to remote server from localhost on 4200 port

Comment: But that's not where the client's requests are going. The proxy isn't magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration should be:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://182.168.0.240:80/",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        },
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And URL is:

```
return this.httpClient.post('/api/accept', order, { headers: headers }).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

It works fine!